# Make prototype method behave differently depending on context

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript "class" which contains a method, `bar()` that I would like to behave differently depending on its context.

In other words, depending on what page I instantiate `blah` on, I would like `bar()` to do different things.

What approach do you suggest here? My first thought was dependency injection in the `blah` constructor.

```
function blah(){
}

blah.prototype.foo = function(){
    bar(arguments);
};
```

Here is an example with different implementations of `bar` in the same method https://jsfiddle.net/7ht8dud6/

Comment: can you provide additional information, for example, some of these different behaviours that you expect?

Comment: @Hitmands Sure, hang on

Comment: Can't you pass all behaviour-related data into `blah` constructor?

Comment: @Hitmands Here is an example with different implementations of the same method https://jsfiddle.net/7ht8dud6/

Comment: @hindmost Yes, that is what I mention in my last sentence :) I suppose that is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update:

By reading your fiddle, in my opinion, you aren't wrong... using a injection in the constructor function can be considered a good practice.

By the way, there are other ways to do what you need.
For example, if the `bar` dependency is required only by the `foo` method you can consider to pass it as a *callback*, this makes the thing more encapsulated and hides the dependency for the rest of the class context:

```js
function Blah() {};

Blah.prototype.foo = function(cb, data) {
  console.count('foo');
  console.log(cb);
  return cb(data);
};

var example = new Blah();

// and use it in this way:
example.foo(
  function(data) { return 1 + data; },
  55
);

// or
example.foo = example.foo.bind(example, function(data) { return data + 1; });
example.foo(4);
example.foo(3);
```

---

Waiting more information as I asked in the above comment, you can consider the `bind` method of the `Function` object, that allows you to pass a different *context* for the execution time.

> [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) - Mozilla Developer Network

A simple example:

```js
function printName() {
  return document
    .getElementById('result')
    .innerText = this.name
  ;
};


function prepareButtons() {
  var list = [
    { name: 'Hitmands', selector: '#btn1' },
    { name: 'Foo', selector: '#btn2' },
    { name: 'Bar', selector: '#btn3' }
  ];
  
  function attach(element, context) {
    element = document.querySelector(element);
    
    return element && element.addEventListener('click', printName.bind(context));
  }
  
  list.forEach(function(item) {
    attach(item.selector, item);
  });
  
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', prepareButtons);
```

```html
<h1 id="result">result</h1>

<button id="btn1">Hitmands</button>
<button id="btn2">Foo</button>
<button id="btn3">Bar</button>
```

Comment: The context is just a matter of what `this` refers to. I think you're misunderstanding the question

Comment: I don't think the OP means the `this` context